# What SQL script can I use to create a two column table where column2 is a Distinct count of Unque IDs for each Column 1 output?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please can someone help me with the SQL script to create a two column table with the following output:

Column1 = List of Distinct Outputs of Param1
Column2 = Distinct count of Unique Param2 outputs for each Column 1 output

Basically, I'm after the SQL script which generates a table with a list of the number of distinct clients (user_pseudo_id) seeing Parm1 using Big Query.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

I've not been able to get a distinct count for param2, so not had much luck with the script.

[image]

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I very much do not understand. What is `param1` and `param2`? Where are they coming from? What do they look like? Why am I writing sql against two parameters as the only input? Your example output has no relevance without example input.

Comment: It sounds like you are just trying to group by the ID column and then count the number of distinct users for each group? If that is the case: SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT(user)) FROM table GROUP BY id should work... But I am also not too sure what your question is.

Comment: Apologies for my poor description. Your suggestion @164_user has worked. Thank you...much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since @164_user's workaround has worked, I will be posting the provided query as a Community Wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

In this case, you want to retrieve the 'id' column and the count of distinct values in the 'user' column for each group.

Query:

```
SELECT id,
COUNT(DISTINCT(user))
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

The result set will include two columns: 'id' and the count of distinct users for each corresponding 'id' group.